# External monitor not working after docking

Tags: multiple-monitors, 15.04, display, thinkpad, docking

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 on my T450s (Intel graphics card) with kernel 4.0.8. I originally updated the kernel to be able to use two external monitors with my ultra dock.

Now, when I dock my running computer, only one of the two monitors display something. Looking in the "Displays" menu, I can see only my laptop screen and one of my monitor.

The workaround I found so far is to either log out or restart the computer, which is pretty annoying. How can I get my two screens working properly when docking my laptop?

Comment: Have the exact same problem here on my t440p with nvidia disabled. - the dock's monitor is initially detected, but fails to detect when running.  It's a bug in something; Consider downgrading to 14.10; it worked much better for me.

Comment: Anyone found an answer to this one?
I have a Lenovo T450s with intel graphics and i encounter the same exact problem. I can book docked, and the two displays connected to the ultradock work just fine. If i then undock, the gnome session restarts and i get an error. If i then redock, the displays are blank and i have to reboot.

Comment: I am still suffering from this bug, so if you ever find something please update the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this: [Kubuntu 15.04 nvidia optimus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614649/kubuntu-15-04-nvidia-optimus). This should help you get everythihg working very smoothly with docking/undocking as well.

/edit

Unless I am mistaken and your laptop does only have the Intel, and not the Nvidia as well. In which case I might be of no help for you.

Comment: My laptop only has an Intel graphics card, so this answer does not apply to my case

Comment: Fir the future, please don't link to answers already on this site, but use the "flag" button to flag them as duplicates...  **;-)**